# Please Explain syntax - flutter bloc provider using inherited widget

Tags: flutter, syntax, bloc, inherited-widget

I do not understand the constructor part and static function part.
super?
dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType?

```
import 'comments_bloc.dart';
export 'comments_bloc.dart';

class CommentsProvider extends InheritedWidget {
  final CommentsBloc commentsBloc;
  CommentsProvider({Key key, Widget child})
      : commentsBloc = CommentsBloc(), // what this line is doing.
        super(key: key, child: child);

  bool updateShouldNotify(_) => true;

//below code?
  static CommentsBloc of(BuildContext context) {
    return context
        .dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<CommentsProvider>()
        .commentsBloc;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1 : The `dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType` method enables a descendant widget to access the closest ancestor `InheritedWidget` instance enclosed in its `BuildContext`, in your code is `CommentsProvider`

Step 2 : And `.commentsBloc` means access this `CommentsProvider` 's attribute, in your code is `final CommentsBloc commentsBloc;`

Comment: what if updateShouldNotify(_) will be like updateShouldNotify(covariant InheritedWidget oldWidget)?